# How to implement non blocking REST web service using Vert.x

Tags: rest, nonblocking, vert.x

I am new into Vert.x. I followed Vert.x documents and some tutorials.But I have confused what is the correct way to implement non blocking REST web service using Vert.x. I found this article [Develop Non-Blocking Web Applications in Java](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-918126re) and this contain a example to implementing Non-Blocking Web Applications using Vert.x.

This code block contain sending a message to a another Vertical(**"todoService":TodoServiceVerticle**).

```
JsonObject command = new JsonObject();

command.putString("action","findOne").
putNumber("id",Long.valueOf(request.params().get("id")));

String address = "todoService";

vertx.eventBus().send(address, command, (Message<JsonObject> message)-> {
    JsonObject item = message.body();
    String payload = item.encode();
    request.response()
       .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
       .end(item);
});
```

This is the **"todoService":TodoServiceVerticle** Vertical.

```
public class TodoServiceVerticle extends Verticle{

    /** Initializes the verticle at the start-up */
    @Override public void start() {   
        // Initialize the verticle
        vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("todoService", this::onMessage);
    }

    private void onMessage(Message<JsonObject> message) {
        JsonObject command = message.body();           
        // Only "findOne" is supported in this example 
        assert ("findOne".equals(command.getString("action")));         
        Long id = command.getLong("id");
        Todo item = findOneById(id);
        JsonObject payload = toJson(item);
        message.reply(payload);
    }
}
```

in this example the **Server** is running on a one Thread.All the http request are coming to the same thread.The **TodoServiceVerticle** is running in a different Thread.

Now my problem is if **TodoServiceVerticle.onMessage()** function contain time consuming task(eg:- DB Operation,Reading a Large File,...),it will block the process.Assume in the same time another user call TodoServiceVerticle.onMessage() but he also have to wait until previous user complete the task.So How to avoid this kind of problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this blog series:

- The [first post](http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/) has described how to build a vert.x application with Maven and execute unit tests.
- The [second post](http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/) has described how this application can become configurable.
- The [third post](http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/) has introduced vertx-web, and a small collection management application has been developed. This application offers a REST API used by a HTML/JavaScript frontend.
- The [fourth post](http://vertx.io/blog/unit-and-integration-tests/) has presented how you can run integration tests to ensure the behavior of your application.
- The [fifth post](http://vertx.io/blog/using-the-asynchronous-sql-client/) has presented how you can interact with a JDBC database using the vertx-jdbc-client.
- And the current last post has presented how you can interact with MongoDB.